# Saving ArrayList Data on Android

Tags: java, android

How can I return to the last question asked in the following code when the application is closed and opened.
I tried to save the arraylist with gson but it does not happen, adding a button also gives an error.
Thanks to you all for your help now.
arraylist got to save with sharedpreferences
because i think sharedpreferences easy than sqlite or another ways

```
private TextView countLabel;
private ImageView questionImage;
private EditText editText;

private String rightAnswer;
private int rightAnswerCount = 0;
private int quizCount = 1;

ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> quizArray = new ArrayList<>();

String quizData[][] = {
        // {"Image Name", "Right Answer"}
        {"image_circle", "circle"},
        {"image_triangle", "triangle"},
        {"image_square", "square"},
        {"image_pentagon", "pentagon"},
        {"image_hexagon", "hexagon"},
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    countLabel = findViewById(R.id.countLabel);
    questionImage = findViewById(R.id.questionImage);
    editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);

    editText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent keyEvent) {

            if (keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                    checkAnswer();
                }

            }

            return false;
        }
    });

    // Create quizArray from quizData.
    for (int i = 0; i < quizData.length; i++) {

        // Prepare array.
        ArrayList<String> tmpArray = new ArrayList<>();
        tmpArray.add(quizData[i][0]); // Image Name
        tmpArray.add(quizData[i][1]); // Right Answer

        // Add tmpArray to quizArray.
        quizArray.add(tmpArray);

    }

    showNextQuiz();
}

public void showNextQuiz() {

    // Update quizCountLabel.
    countLabel.setText("Q" + quizCount);

    // Generate random number between 0 and 4 (quizArray's size -1)
    Random random = new Random();
    int randomNum = random.nextInt(quizArray.size());

    // Pick one quiz set.
    ArrayList<String> quiz = quizArray.get(randomNum);

    // Set image and right answer.
    // Array format: {"Image Name", "Right Answer"}
    questionImage.setImageResource(
            getResources().getIdentifier(quiz.get(0), "drawable", getPackageName()));
    rightAnswer = quiz.get(1);

    // Remove this quiz from quizArray.
    quizArray.remove(randomNum);
}


public void checkAnswer() {

    // Get editText.
    String answer = editText.getText().toString().toLowerCase();

    String alertTitle;

    if (answer.equals(rightAnswer)) {
        // Correct!
        alertTitle = "Correct!";
        rightAnswerCount++;
    } else {
        // Wrong...
        alertTitle = "Wrong...";
    }

    // Create Dialog.
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(alertTitle);
    builder.setMessage("Answer : " + rightAnswer);
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            editText.setText("");

            if (quizArray.size() < 1) {
                // quizArray is empty.
                showResult();

            } else {
                quizCount++;
                showNextQuiz();
            }

        }
    });
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.show();
}

public void showResult() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Result");
    builder.setMessage(rightAnswerCount + " / 5");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Try Again", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            recreate();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Quit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            finish();
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
```

}

Thanks to you all for your help now.

Comment: You can use shared preferences and store your arrays key, you don't need to store your whole array. When you want to restore the last question, create your array again check the value stored in the shared preferences. Using sharing preferences is not an issue of here but for tutorials,

Comment: https://www.journaldev.com/9412/android-shared-preferences-example-tutorial

Comment: dostum sana sosyal medyadan ulaşabilir miyim bir kaç haftadır bu konu hakkında epey kafa yordum ama yapamadım